# Lenovo Thinkpad X230t Tablet Pinch Zoom Not Working on Touch Screen on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, thinkpad, lenovo-laptop, touchscreen, tablet-pc

Googled for hours, until eventually found the solution.  Posting this to help others.

After re-installing Windows 10 from scratch, my touchscreen pinch-to-zoom does not work.  No zoom happens by touch, only by CTRL + and CTRL - on the keyboard.

PC is a Lenovo Thinkpad X230 Tablet PC with a Touchscreen.  It supports multi-touch, and Windows worked with "pinch zoom" before this re-install.

Lots of articles and Superuser.com help says go to Control Panel -> Mouse -> Additional Mouse Options -> Device Settings, but after installing the Lenovo Thinkpad touchpad drivers, the Device Settings is replaced with a Thinkpad tab.  Only options available are Touchpad settings, including  pinch-and-zoom on the touchpad (not touch screen).  There is no way to enable or disable the touch-screen's pinch-to-zoom feature.

Maybe this issue was caused by the order I installed the drivers?

Answer (score 1):

The fix for me was to download this driver from Wacom:

https://www.wacom.com/en-hk/support/tablet-pc-support

Once installed, pinch-to-zoom works on the touch screen.

Hope this helps someone!